# Is there a way to find out what a stored procedure returns without running it?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to build a designer in .NET, and would like to be able to retrieve the columns and column types of the output from a stored procedure without calling it so the designer can be used to map the output. Is this possible? I'm even willing to use an unmanaged API if necessary.

Comment: Don't think so. See related [Microsoft Connect Item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/525653/stored-procedures-should-expose-detailed-contracts). Edit: Although actually the Visual Studio strongly typed dataset designer does this to a limited extent...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is `SET FMTONLY` ([Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173839.aspx)).

This allows you to execute a SP (or select statement) and see what columns would be returned without actually executing the query.

Comment: Via SQL Profiler, I have seen ODBC, OLE-DB, and/or other low-level APIs use this trick. Upvoted, though I'm not sure how easy it would be to use.

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work. It appears to return all possible return values, even when they are conditionally returned.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible, in general, because even a single stored procedure can return different result sets, with different columns or column data types.

Answer (score 0):

In extreme cases even the number of returned result sets may depend on parameters and when the stored procedure uses dynamic sql its definitely impossible.